# ASP.NET Server Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

are the required fields validators, compare validators etc server side validations or client side validations?

Thanks

Comment: both you can go through this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa479013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The validators generally do both client and server-side, but it all depends on how you configure them. Look for an [`EnableClientScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) property. If you build a custom validator, you can supply server code, client code, or both, but you have to write the code for both sides independently.

Answer (score 0):

They'll run on the client (unless [`EnableClientScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) is `false`) and prevent submission of the form if it's invalid.  They will also run on the server, if the client-side checks are bypassed.  Be sure to check [`Page.IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) before taking action in event handlers (the event handler still runs, even if server-side validation fails).

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation I've heard is

1. **Client side validation** is for the user's benefit (for the reasons @Garry explained in his answer above).
2. **Server side validation** is for the benefit of system integrity (also for the reasons @Garry explained in his answer above).